# babel-plugin-rewire breaks should.js import?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, should.js

I encountered a weird problem when trying to use `babel-plugin-rewire`and `should.js` assertion library in my tests. With my current configuration I cannot require `should` to a variable:

```
const should = require('should')
console.log('should through variable: ', should)  // --> undefined !!!
console.log('should through require: ', require('should'))  // --> function should...
```

Tests are run using command

```
NODE_ENV=test mocha --compilers js:babel-register --require babel-polyfill --require should
```

The problem goes away if I comment out the `rewire` plugin from my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "es2015-node4", "async-to-bluebird"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      // "plugins": ["babel-plugin-rewire"]
    }
  }
}
```

... but then I cannot use the rewire functionality.

Do you have any clues how to get `babel-plugin-rewire` and `should.js` work together?

The used library versions are:

```
"babel-plugin-rewire": "^1.0.0-rc-3",
"should": "^7.1.0",
```

Comment: What if you will remove `--require should` from run test cmd?

Comment: Removing `--require should` didn't seem to change anything. It's there to provide object property based assertions like `someString.should.equal('foo')`.

Comment: If you will create working example that clearly show an issue (that i pull and just run) create an issue in should.js i will try to help.

Comment: Okay, here's quite minimal gist about the problem: https://gist.github.com/ronkot/2babe4b777d7bcb4053b9747d9c59346

Comment: Not sure why but your example working fine for me.

Comment: @denbardadym Actually the error in the gist is not that `should` would be undefined, but that trying to print the object to console causes a `ReferenceError: _get__ is not defined`. I couldn't replicate the original issue but I'm quite sure that the root cause of these two errors is the same.

What does your test run give as output? Mine gives: `[ReferenceError: _get__ is not defined]
should through require:  function should(obj) {
  return (new should.Assertion(obj));
}`